# WinApi, ::TextOut with different fonts (like Tahoma) bug

Tags: c++, winapi, text, fonts, textout

guys. I found really strange problem. With some fonts (there is a ChooseFont in my program) ::TextOut(..) draw text a little offset to the left from chosen position (smth like 2 pxl). DrawText(..) goes the same way. SetTextAlign DON'T solve this problem! GetTextMetrics(..) -> lpOverhead = 0.Ehm... and when i calculate next position using GetExtendPoint32(..) it also do not consider that offset. I got no help both on biggest russian forum and MSDN. Help please, it's really not a simple problem. Test it before answering. Here is the simplest code example.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
int wmId, wmEvent;
PAINTSTRUCT ps;
HDC hdc;
HFONT font =(HFONT) GetStockObject(DEFAULT_GUI_FONT);
switch (message)
{
case WM_COMMAND:
    wmId    = LOWORD(wParam);
    wmEvent = HIWORD(wParam);
    // Разобрать выбор в меню:
    switch (wmId)
    {
    case IDM_ABOUT:
        DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
        break;
    case IDM_EXIT:
        DestroyWindow(hWnd);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    break;
case WM_PAINT:
    hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    // TODO: добавьте любой код отрисовки...
    SelectObject(hdc,font);
    ::TextOut(hdc,0,0,L"fff",3); //first "f" written not fully
    EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    break;
case WM_DESTROY:
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    break;
default:
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is normal.  The common approach is to add padding, GDI+ for example internally adds 1/6th of the font height in pixels, rounded up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue. GetCharABCWidths(..). Return widths A,B,C (beforechar,char,afterchar). Some fonts have A<0, which cause TextOut() and DrawText() ehm draw text with offset to the left.